# Android project in Eclipse is missing the Android 4.2.2 library folder

Tags: android, eclipse

SOLVED - After doing what you all helped me with, a restart of Eclipse fixed it. Thanks

One of my Android apps in Eclipse is showing red errors for all my lines of code, and when I looked to find the problem, there was no Android 4.2.2 library in the project. I don't know where it went, but I'd like to know how I get it back.

It also says "Unable to get system library for project" in the library tab of Build Path.

If these responses don't work, I might just create a new project and put back in the required files.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Right Click on Project->Properties->Android->Select 4.2.2 in your target name
2. If there is no 4.2.2 in your target then you probably need to download 4.2.2 api from sdk manager.

Comment: Try cleaning your project: Project > Clean and try restarting eclipse then

Answer (score 6):

If the other answers don't help, try right clicking the folder of your project and then going to "Android Tools", then "Fix Project Properties". If you happen to delete your dependencies in the Package Explorer in Eclipse, this will bring them right back!

Comment: @clever_trevor do you still have the 4.2.2 sdk? Try going to the sdk manager and deleting that sdk, and then downloading it again. It might have accidentally been deleted or corrupted.

Comment: Hmm, can you go to the properties window for your project, then taking a screenshot of what's in "Android 4.2.2" under the "Libraries" tab and post it here? That'd be a lot of help. If not, I just want to know if "android.jar" is inside of the 4.2.2 library

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project ==> Select Android ==> Select Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Charlie pretty much gave the exact answer you did and yet he gets an upvote and you down voted. Makes no sense

Comment: Try Cleaning your Project by going to Project ==> Clean.. If it still doesn't work, try restarting your eclipse and create a new project to see if the error persists.

Comment: There might be a problem with your Android SDK preferences. Check them once.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading other built target, e.g. Android 4.3, so you can do this:
Select other project built target (e.g. Google APIs 4.3), click OK. 
Repeat the same steps to select Android 4.2.2.